# Delete the contents of the SI4T index

Tags: 2013-sp1, si4t

We have done a content synchronization from our live environment to our UAT test environment (in other words, a backup and restore of our CM database to UAT). After doing so, we wanted to clear the SI4T index, because there are items in that index that used to exist on UAT, but no longer exist on UAT after the content has been synchronized from live. We can't remove those Pages from the index, because they now don't exist on UAT with the listed TCM id, so there is no such Page to unpublish.

Is there a way for us to completely clear the SI4T index, so that we can republish all of the items, to subsequently re-populate the index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use:

```
http://host:port/solr/core/update?
      stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```

To ensure nothing breaks when you delete the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I worked this out. To do this, I needed to delete the contents of the 'index' directory on the SOLR server (at '\\data\index'), and subsequently restart Apache Tomcat.